How to detect smartd errors from logs
I want to monitor multiple servers, and want to know when a drive fails.
I have a script which monitors /var/log/syslog. What i want is a regex that matches only when a drive has a big problem. I do not care when the temperature changes. Only when there is clear sign that the drive is bad.
Anyone has some tip?

I think no one knows what indicate a critical error. If you want to choose here are the options smartd authors think worth an email. Good luck parsing.
$ grep MailWarning smartd.cpp
...
    MailWarning(cfg, state, 0, "TEST EMAIL from smartd for device: %s", name);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 9, "Device: %s, unable to open %s device", name, type);
    MailWarning(cfg, state, 8, "Device: %s, Read SMART Self-Test Log Failed", name);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 3, "Device: %s, Self-Test Log error count increased from %d to %d",
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 3, "Device: %s, new Self-Test Log error at hour timestamp %d",
  MailWarning(cfg, state, mailtype, "%s", s.c_str());
    MailWarning(cfg, state, 12, "Device: %s, Temperature %d Celsius reached critical limit of %u Celsius (Min/Max %s%s/%u%s)",
    MailWarning(cfg, state, 2, "Device: %s, Failed SMART usage Attribute: %d %s.", cfg.name.c_str(), attr.id, attrname.c_str());
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 5, "Device: %s, not capable of SMART self-check", name);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 1, "Device: %s, FAILED SMART self-check. BACK UP DATA NOW!", name);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 6, "Device: %s, failed to read SMART Attribute Data", name);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 7, "Device: %s, Read SMART Error Log Failed", name);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 4, "Device: %s, ATA error count increased from %d to %d",
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 6, "Device: %s, failed to read SMART values", name);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 1,"Device: %s, SMART Failure: %s", name, cp);
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 6, "Device: %s, failed to read NVMe SMART/Health Information", name);
    MailWarning(cfg, state, 1, "Device: %s, Critical Warning (0x%02x): %s", name, w, msg.c_str());
      MailWarning(cfg, state, 4, "Device: %s, number of Error Log entries increased from %" PRIu64 " to %" PRIu64,
...
  std::string s = strprintf("Device: %s, %" PRId64 " %s", cfg.name.c_str(), rawval, msg);
  if (prev_rawval > 0 && rawval != prev_rawval)
    s += strprintf(" (changed %+" PRId64 ")", rawval - prev_rawval);
    MailWarning(cfg, state, 2, "%s", msg.c_str());



smartd sends mail notifications by itself. By default they are sent to root, but you can configure your mta to send root mail somewhere else (which is a pretty good idea anyway).
For example, for postfix it is as easy as adding a single line to /etc/aliases:
root: anothermail@example.com

don't forget to run postmap on the file
